# An algorithm for solving linear diophantine equations?

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations, contest-math

I am entering an interesting team based math contest called the purple comet, and quite a lot of questions on this contest involve Diophantine equations. For this contest, you are given a computer, and I was thinking of making a program that solved a linear Diophantine equation. The issue with this is that I can barely solve one by hand, much less make a rigorous algorithm to solve one. I am aware of Euclid's algorithm, but when the numbers get big, this method gets pretty inefficient, not to mention that it would be kind of a nasty thing to program. Are there any other smart algorithms out there for solving a linear Diophantine equation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917003/whats-algorithm-used-to-solve-linear-diophantine-equation-ax-by-c.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, Wow, thanks. Guess I didn't look hard enough. Is it considered a duplicate if it's asked on a different branch of stack exchange? If so, I'll gladly vote to close.

Comment: No, it isn't considered a duplicate if it's asked on a different branch of stack exchange.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, Great! In any case, I'd kind of like 3 or 4 algorithms so that I can test them out and see which one is more efficient, though I know that's asking for a bit much.

Comment: Are you really a middle-schooler? I am just curious, because I am 13, and in middle-school, too.

Comment: I am, though I'm surprised that someone my age knows so much about quantum mechanics and calculus. I'm just beginning to learn calculus myself, but don't yet know enough to apply it to physics.

Comment: Good luck! It'll be a fun journey!

Comment: Just curious, what type of a 13 year old is a theoretical physicist? Either you're lying about your age or your occupation, and I believe the one you're lying about is the former.

Comment: I'm telling the truth - I'm a theoretical physicist! I do research on topological quantum field theory and moduli spaces of string theories. I also study twistor string theory.

Comment: The former being your age...

Comment: I'm thirteen (to turn fourteen in April) - I promise!

Comment: I'm thirteen, but I do not like to think that I am a genius. However, thanks for the complement!

Comment: So have you given any thought to my question? It hasn't received many views, and the only response I got was in the form of your comments.

Comment: I am not an expert in the field of algorithms, and the only reference I could find was the link I earlier posted. I am sorry that I cannot be of much help.

Comment: Funny! They are using a computer solve a system of linear equations. This requires a pen and piece of paper! A system of nonlinear equations probably do not know how to solve it? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757664/system-of-diophantine-equations  That's how they should be solved.